# The condition for intersection of closed set to be empty

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $\{A_n\}$ be the decreasing sequence of non empty closed subsets of $X$. Then Cantor's intersection theorem tells that if $d(A_n) \to 0$ then the set $A = \cap_{i} A_i$ consists a single point.

If any of the above conditions are dropped then $A$ would not be a singleton set. Suppose if we drop the condition of decreasing sequence then $A$ may not be bounded or if we drop closedness of $A_i$ then $A$ may be empty.

Now if we drop the condition $d(A_i) \to 0$ then I intuitively feel that $A$ should be non empty even though I'm not able to prove that or to find any counter examples. Does there exist a sequence like the diameter of them does not go to 0 but intersection is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_n$ be the closed interval $[n,\infty)$.  They are decreasing but have empty intersection.

Comment: And if anyone is bothered by the fact that the diameters are all infinite in this case, they can just replace $d$ with the equivalent metric $\frac{d}{1+d}$.